# Typechecking error involving the andalso macro in ATS

Tags: ats

Here are two pieces of code I think are equivalent aside from the second one having more lines then it should:

```
fun
move_ul
{i:nat}
(
  p: int(i) 
, ms: list0(Int)
): list0(Int) =
if p - 5 >= 0 andalso p % 4 != 0 then
  move_ul(p - 5, cons0(p - 5, ms))
else
  ms



fun
move_ul
{i:nat}
(
  p: int(i) 
, ms: list0(Int)
): list0(Int) =
if p % 4 != 0 then
  if p - 5 >= 0 then
    move_ul(p - 5, cons0(p - 5, ms))
  else
    ms
else
  ms
```

For some reason the second one survives type checking and the first does not (failure to satisfy constraints)... can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the way `andalso` is defined (as a macro that does not use dependent types). If you change `andalso` to `*` (which overloads the boolean multiplication), the first version of your code should typecheck.

By the way, if `orelse` is used, a similar situation can simply be resolved by replacing `orelse` with `+` (which overloads the boolean addition).